# Apache Guacamole Web client not showing any connections

Tags: tomcat8, guacamole

I have set up Apache Guacamole with AD authentication and Postgres; everything seems to be right but  I am not able to see any button to create any connection. Does anyone have any idea how to troubleshoot this?

- I initialized the database
- logs show a successful connection
- I used a master DB account in the property files to role out any permission issue.
- Tables are in place.
  I am not able to see any connection. anyone has any idea how to troubleshoot this.

database tables:

```
Schema |                 Name                  | Type  | Owner  
--------+---------------------------------------+-------+--------
 public | guacamole_connection                  | table | master
 public | guacamole_connection_attribute        | table | master
 public | guacamole_connection_group            | table | master
 public | guacamole_connection_group_attribute  | table | master
 public | guacamole_connection_group_permission | table | master
 public | guacamole_connection_history          | table | master
 public | guacamole_connection_parameter        | table | master
 public | guacamole_connection_permission       | table | master
 public | guacamole_entity                      | table | master
 public | guacamole_sharing_profile             | table | master
 public | guacamole_sharing_profile_attribute   | table | master
 public | guacamole_sharing_profile_parameter   | table | master
 public | guacamole_sharing_profile_permission  | table | master
 public | guacamole_system_permission           | table | master
 public | guacamole_user                        | table | master
 public | guacamole_user_attribute              | table | master
 public | guacamole_user_group                  | table | master
 public | guacamole_user_group_attribute        | table | master
 public | guacamole_user_group_member           | table | master
 public | guacamole_user_group_permission       | table | master
 public | guacamole_user_history                | table | master
 public | guacamole_user_password_history       | table | master
 public | guacamole_user_permission             | table | master
(23 rows)
```

No available connection button to create new connection
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have import all the `sql` files available in guacamole, it will create an admin user for you by default with the following details.

```
username: guacadmin  
password: guacadmin
```

After you login, you will see empty connections screen (As you shown above).

To create new connection, Click on the username at the top right (a sub menu will appear), click on **Settings**.

[image: guacamole home page]

You will see several tabs here. To create connection, go to **Connection** tab, and click on **'New Connection'** button.
[image]